# No C compiler on EC2?

Tags: linux, gcc, amazon-ec2, configure

I've been trying to install Gearman on my EC2 instance, but when I try to ./configure gearmand, I get this:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/ec2-user/gearmand-1.1.3':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

Now, the strange thing is that GCC is most definitely installed.

```
which gcc46
```

returns

```
/usr/bin/gcc46
```

However, when I try to run the command "gcc", it's not found...

I've tried to erase/intall/reinstall gcc and gcc-c++ via yum, but that doesn't seem to be helping.

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ln /usr/bin/gcc46 /usr/bin/gcc`?

Comment: EC2 isn't an operating system.  Which OS do you have installed?  If it's a Red Hat-derived system like "Amazon Linux" "yum install gcc" will work.  On Debian-like systems (Ubuntu, etc...) use "aptitude install gcc".

Comment: `./configure CC=gcc46`; configure won't be likely to look for the version-decorated name.

Comment: Often, it is spelled `gcc-4.6` not `gcc46` and very often just `gcc` (or even `cc`)

Comment: @CallumRogers linking it worked :) thanks for all the advice everyone!

Comment: @GhostCode: I added the comment-answer as a proper answer-answer :)

Comment: For Ubuntu: sudo aptitude install gcc

Comment: For Red Hat: sudo yum install gcc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get around this by linking `/usr/bin/gcc` to `/usr/bin/gcc46` using this command:

```
ln /usr/bin/gcc46 /usr/bin/gcc
```

When you upgrade `gcc`, you can then keep multiple versions with binaries named `/usr/bin/gccXX` and simple point the `/usr/bin/gcc` link to the version you want to use (which will probably be the newest one).