# Amazon Linux; gcc: command not found

Tags: linux, gcc, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running Amazon Linux(redhat OS) in EC2.

When I try to rpmbuild a tar I got stuck with this one

```
checking for x86_64-redhat-linux-gcc... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for x86_64-redhat-linux-cc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for x86_64-redhat-linux-cl.exe... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/falko/rpm/BUILD/courier-unicode-1.1':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.RkeUmM (%prep)
```

when I try to check the ff:

```
$ rpm -q gcc
gcc-4.8.2-3.19.amzn1.noarch
```

And

```
$ gcc -v
-bash: gcc: command not found
```

And

```
# which gcc
/usr/bin/which: no gcc in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin)
```

I even tried to install it again

```
# yum install gcc
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                         | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                      | 2.3 kB     00:00
Package gcc-4.8.2-3.19.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

And even remove and reinstall it, I had tried. No luck for me. Can someone please help me about this one I am just trying to install a mail server.

```
$ sudo find / -name gcc -exec stat "{}" ";"
File: ‘/usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc’
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: ca01h/51713d    Inode: 33142       Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2014-03-08 00:09:16.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2014-08-01 10:17:15.793438394 +0000
Change: 2014-08-01 10:17:15.793438394 +0000
 Birth: -
  File: ‘/usr/lib/gcc’
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: ca01h/51713d    Inode: 18082       Links: 3
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2014-03-25 01:30:05.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2014-03-25 01:30:05.000000000 +0000
Change: 2014-07-24 00:39:05.646351830 +0000
 Birth: -
  File: ‘/usr/libexec/gcc’
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: ca01h/51713d    Inode: 18392       Links: 3
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2014-03-25 01:30:05.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2014-07-24 00:39:02.206416684 +0000
Change: 2014-07-24 00:39:02.206416684 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Post `sudo find / -name gcc -exec stat "{}" ";"`

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/13327320/612920

Comment: when I tried to use which gcc I got /usr/bin/which: no gcc in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin)

Comment: Post `find /usr -name "gcc*" -type f`

Comment: I think I got it I used gcc48 base on the gcc version I got and make a link to /usr/bin/gcc; Thanks! It work but another problem is "C compiler cannot create exsucutables"

Comment: @SamPinkus pls still help me with this one

Comment: Not sure exactly why you would get that error. Looks like a linker error. Try with executing `gcc48` directly, and also try compiling a really simple binary like `#include <stdio.h>; int main() { printf('Hi');}`. And see what error you get.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by executing directly, how can I do that? sorry Im a newbie

Comment: I think I understand it shows me "fatal error: cannot find 'ld'" what does it mean?

Comment: Thanks, but as of now all development are already installed and on its latest version