# gcc creates a different folder base on its version

Tags: c, gcc, amazon-ec2

When I try to **rpmbuild** something I got this error message

```
checking for x86_64-redhat-linux-gcc... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for x86_64-redhat-linux-cc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for x86_64-redhat-linux-cl.exe... no
checking for cl.exe... no
```

And I found out that, the tool are in /usr/bin/gcc48 what I did is link the gcc48 to gcc folder: Which I got the idea from this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/13327320/612920

```
ln /usr/bin/gcc48 /usr/bin/gcc
```

And when I tried to run **rpmbuild** again I got this error message:

```
checking for x86_64-redhat-linux-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/usr/src/rpm/BUILD/courier-unicode-1.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.jrbnrw (%prep)
```

What is wrong? I had already installed all development tools and its on its latest versions. Can Somebody help me?

And by the way I am using Amazons Redhat (gcc version 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7) (GCC))

**UPDATED:**

config.log

```
configure:3499: $? = 0
configure:3488: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/4.8.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-amazon-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugu$
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7) (GCC)
configure:3499: $? = 0
configure:3488: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3499: $? = 4
configure:3488: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3499: $? = 4
configure:3519: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3541: gcc -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp$
collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
compilation terminated.
configure:3545: $? = 1
configure:3583: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| int
| main ()
| {
|
|   ;

|   return 0;
| }
configure:3588: error: in `/home/falko/rpm/BUILD/courier-unicode-1.1':
configure:3590: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Comment: No need for `C++` tag, right?  You'd use `gcc++` for compiling `C++`?

Comment: Can you add the contents of config.log to your question? At least the bit where it errors out

Comment: @harmic I already updated my question, I only get the problem part of the config.log. So if you need more info pls just tell me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a couple of research I had found out that I am just lacking of **ld**(GNU linker) tool from RedHat's developer tool set and I also found out that there is an alternative tool just in case **ld**(GNU linker) is not available, **ld.bfd**(alternative to the GNU linker) which is in my case it is available. What I did, I make a link from **ld.bfd** to **ld**:

```
ln /usr/bin/ld.bfd /usr/bin/ld
```

I don't know if it is the proper solution but it works for me.

Reference: [Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/1/html/User_Guide/chap-binutils.html)

Answer (score 0):

`gcc` is one of a number of tools required to build a software package, and as you can see from the error in your config.log, some more are missing from your system:

```
collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
```

It is complaining that it cannot find the system linker (ld).

Before addressing this, I recommend you set the gcc version to be used correctly. Unfortunately the advice you followed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13327320/612920 is somewhat incomplete.

Redhat based systems provide a mechanism for being able to switch between different implementations of a piece of software at will (for example, different versions). This tool is called [alternatives](http://linux.die.net/man/8/alternatives). You should use that to set the GCC version that will be used when you run 'gcc' at the command line. It will update a whole set of symlinks, not just the one you manually set.

```
sudo alternatives --config gcc
```

After doing this set the linker to be used:

```
sudo alternatives --config ld
```

Note that when I've tried out an AMI linux image, I found that by installing gcc like this:

```
sudo yum install gcc48
```

it automatically set the correct 'alternatives' for the newly installed compiler and corresponding linker. I'm not sure how your system got into the state that it is currently in, but if you still have problems after the above procedure, I recommend uninstalling and re-installing gcc and binutils.

Comment: I tried to do the things you said I even reached in re-installing gcc and binutils, but still not ok. Is it possible because i dont have /usr/bin/ld? and I only see ldd does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks harmic for your answer, although it is not the right answer I am looking, I had learned something from it.