# howto install pycuda on Amazon Web Service EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, installation, pycuda

can anybody help me to install pycuda on this Deep Learning Base AMI (Amazon Linux) Version 11.0, please? I use p2.xlarge type.

I get this error:
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

i tried  to link the ccp1plus but no success:
sudo ln -s /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/4.8.5/cc1plus /usr/local/bin/

other solutions on the web can't help too.

thank for your help,

Looninho

Answer (score 1):

It looks like gcc is not included in that AMI. According to [this StackOverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326984/no-c-compiler-on-ec2/13327320#13327320), you may be able to just update the gcc symlink:

```
ln /usr/bin/gcc46 /usr/bin/gcc
```